# Mongoose replaces updated object at array index with undefined before running update query

Tags: mongoose

I have a `layer` document in mongodb containing points on a map.  The points are an array.  To update a point at a specific index, I use the following code:

```
            var query;
            if (req.body.isNew)
                query = { $push: { 'points': point } }
            else
                query = { $set: { ['points.' + pointIndex]: point } };

            console.log("QUERY IS: ", query)
            Layers.update({ _id: layer._id }, query, (err, result) => {
                if (err || !layer) {
                    console.error(err);
                    res.status(400).json({ "error": "error updating" })
                    return;
                }
                res.status(200).json({ success: true });
            });
            console.log("RAN query");
```

What you will see is that the query is correctly generated to update a specific code a given index.   However, when mongoose runs the query, IT REPLACES THE POINT WITH `undefined`!  Why is it doing this?  This is the console output (I have mongoose set to log queries it runs):

```
QUERY IS:  { '$set':
   { 'points.0':
      { _id: '58389c52d1fc2dcb1d9f06d1',
        lat: 39.605688178320804,
        lng: -98.9208984375,
        customFieldValues: {},
        tasks: [],
        name: 'abcd',
        updatedAt: 2016-11-25T20:17:32.995Z,
        updatedBy: 'bobbington@mailinator.com' } } }
RAN query
Mongoose: layers.update({ _id: ObjectId("58387d06b549e03c588993eb") }, { '$set': { 'points.0': undefined } }, {})
```

Answer (score 0):

Downgraded to Mongoose 4.5.3 and it works!  This is why I should be using yarn instead of NPM.